# As Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) seems to be the holy grail to much of the threats, are there any cases where MFA is compromised?

Tags: multi-factor

As Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) seems to be the holy grail to much of the threats we see today, are there any cases where MFA is breached or compromised? What are the threat vectors to MFA?

Comment: This is trivial to research. https://www.google.com/search?q=attacks+on+MFA or https://www.google.com/search?q=mfa+compromised Please make sure that you have done some research before posting here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks research effort or it is too undefined if research was done.

Answer (score 1):

Multi Factor is not a "holy-grail" or silver bullet to account take over, but it makes it significantly more difficult.

[SMS based Multi Factor](https://auth0.com/blog/why-sms-multi-factor-still-matters/) is notable for its issue. And other multi factor solutions have their issues as well. For example, if you loose your phone and use an app for multifactor, you suddenly lost access to that app.

One of the bigger issue with multi-factor is the same one that plagued is social engineering and phishing. If someone can be tricked into authenticating or give in the sms/ app  code. The are still compromised.

Multifactor really good in situations of password re-use or weak passwords.

Fido2 keys and [webauthn](https://www.yubico.com/authentication-standards/webauthn/) will be resistant more phishing, but they will still have issue, such as loss or stolen fob or social engineering.

Another major weakness of the MFA is where it can be bypassed entirely, MFA does not add as much security when people leave logged in laptops/phone or etc unlocked and unattended.